# Further uncertainties in magnetostatic

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

In magnetostatic, the continuity equation is as follows:

$$\frac {\partial\rho(\vec r,t)}{\partial t} + \nabla \vec j(\vec r,t)=0$$

In magnetostatic $\frac {\partial\rho(\vec r,t)}{\partial t}=0$ and this means $\nabla \vec j(\vec r,t)=0$. This is pretty straightforward and I am able to understand it.

At the same time we know the relation between electric current density and electric field:

$$\vec j(\vec r)= \sigma \vec E(\vec r)$$$\sigma$ is the electric conductivity of the medium.

Combining the 2 equations together and considering that we are in magnetostatic, we have:

$$\sigma \nabla \vec E(\vec r)=0$$.
Now if we consider  the relation between electric displacement and electric field: $\vec D(\vec r) =\epsilon_0 \epsilon(\vec r)\vec E(\vec r)$ and that $\nabla \vec D(\vec r)=\rho_{free}$, we can write the above equation as:
$$\frac \sigma{\epsilon_0 \epsilon}\nabla \vec D(\vec r) = \frac \sigma{\epsilon_0 \epsilon}\rho_{free}=0$$ and this yields $\rho_{free}=0$. And here is the asymmetry that I encounter.

Initially $\nabla \vec j(\vec r,t)=0$  because $\frac {\partial\rho(\vec r,t)}{\partial t}=0$. In other words the divergence of the current is zero because the electric charges do not accelerate in magnetostatic.

On the other side I derived that $\nabla \vec j(\vec r,t)=0$ because $\rho_{free}=0$. We have no free charges in the medium and therefore the divergence of the electric current is zero.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: That's because you assumed an extra constraint on $\rho$ via Ohm's law. So the first constraint on $\rho$ is that it's time independent making $J$ divergence-free (via continuity equation). The second constraint is via Ohm's law, if you take the divergence of $J$ you get zero hence divergence of $E$ must be zero as well hence $\rho$ is zero as well. So the only type of $\rho$ which is consistent with the two types of constraints you stated (continuity equation + Ohm's law) is evidently the zero function.

Comment: So what you are saying is that in order for both of these equations to be true, we must not have free charge density, it must be zero?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Then, if you don't have free charges in the medium, in other words you don't have free charge density, how can you have current?

Comment: You don't have to have charge to have a current. This is a common confusion since current density is defined as $\rho v$ but it's actually better written as $J = \rho_- v_- + \rho_+ v_+$. and you can have situations where $\rho_- + \rho_+ = 0$ ($\rho = 0$) which doesn't imply that $J = 0$. Just image the case where $v_+ = 0$ -- this in fact corresponds to what happens in real situations: positive charges like protons are stationary but electrons are moving although the overall macroscopic charge density is zero (equal number of electrons and protons) but there is still current.

Comment: Just to be clear: $\rho_- $refers to charge density of negative charges and $v_-$ refers to the speed of those charge carriers (so think for simplicity electrons). The same goes for $\rho_+$ and $v_+$ which refer to the density and speed of positive charge carriers. And in fact in usual magnetostatics problems we implicitly assume the above: we have a current but the overall charge density is zero at each point.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation